# Not able to update helm chart from jenkins from S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, kubernetes-helm, kubectl

I have a problem with deployment where I am using helm charts.

First I added the s3 using `helm repo add myapp s3://helm-chart-repository` and I can see that repo in `helm repo list`

```
NAME    URL                          
myapp   s3://helm-chart-repository   
stable  https://charts.helm.sh/stable
```

Helm chart definition is located on S3 server, but I am not able to get anything from S3 for some reason

```
Hang tight while we grab the latest from your chart repositories...
fetch from s3 uri=s3://helm-chart-repository/index.yaml: fetch object from s3: AccessDenied: Access Denied
    status code: 403, request id: 28E6B839DA0AAD07, host id: HGJb2xx3rxyDpFlwb5U/fu8SfR7PK6ahn6nfRQPYluJhdJKzFyApZOielT6BIiC0wnnFHnqeG1k=
...Unable to get an update from the "myapp" chart repository (s3://helm-chart-repository):
    plugin "bin/helms3" exited with error
```

If I list all charts, it actually shows all charts from `myapp` repo.

And if I run `kubectl cluster-info`, I can see that there is a configuration

```
0;32mKubernetes master[0m is running at [0;33mhttps://api.staging.k8s.myapp.com[0m
[0;32mKubeDNS[0m is running at [0;33mhttps://api.staging.k8s.myapp.com/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/kube-dns:dns/proxy[0m
```

Answer (score 1):

As you didnt not mention in the post how you are using this ( like is it `cross account` or via `aws_profile`). I am assuming you simply setting it up with S3 bucket.

In that case you are missing read/write policy. I am mentioning both policies `IAM` as well as `S3 Bucket` below.

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "files",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObjectAcl",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObjectAcl",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:DeleteObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name/repository-name/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name/repository-name"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "bucket",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:ListBucket",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name"
        }
    ]
}
```

```json
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "AllowListObjects",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": ["arn:aws:iam::111122223333:user/username"]
      },
      "Action": [
        "s3:ListBucket"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-helm-charts"
    },
    {
      "Sid": "AllowObjectsFetchAndCreate",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": ["arn:aws:iam::111122223333:user/username"]
      },
      "Action": [
        "s3:DeleteObject",
        "s3:GetObject",
        "s3:PutObject"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-helm-charts/*"
    }
  ]
}
```

[helms3](https://github.com/hypnoglow/helm-s3)

[How to create a Helm chart repository using Amazon S3](https://andrewlock.net/how-to-create-a-helm-chart-repository-using-amazon-s3/)

Comment: It is using `Access control list (ACL)` where `bucket owner` has read/write access

Is it okay to mix that with one of the policies that you mentioned above?

Comment: @Boban `bucket-owner-full-control` [Both the object owner and the bucket owner get FULL_CONTROL over the object. If you specify this canned ACL when creating a bucket, Amazon S3 ignores it.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/acl-overview.html#canned-acl). So the objects must be updated with corresponding ACL.